# .htaccess rewriterule - check for referrer, if wrong referrer send to a specific URL, if right, allow directory to be read

Tags: .htaccess

I have a folder on my site (domain.com/protect) I want to limit to only one referrer (otherdomain.com/subfolder).

Deny for all others, allow only if coming from that URL.

If not coming from that URL, then redirect the visitor over to otherdomain.com/login instead.

How would I write that out in .htaccess rewrite rules?

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file in your `/protect` directory, add these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !otherdomain\.com/subfolder
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

The condition checks that the referer doesn't contain: `otherdomain.com/subfolder`, and if it doesn't, then whatever the request is (inside the `/protect` directory) will result in a 403 Forbidden.

Alternatively, you can put these rules in the htaccess file in your document root if you would rather keep everything in once place:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !otherdomain\.com/subfolder
RewriteRule ^/?protect/? - [L,F]
```