# htaccess rewriting rules according referrer

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The rewriting conditions in htaccess break down some inbound clicks coming from some referrers (google, bing: sponsored ads) . These urls leading to the website  use parameters for tracking purpose.

Please, Is it possible to set some htaccess exception rules for those specific urls coming from sponsored links ? (for instance do not to set any rewriting rules for urls with specific uri (domain, parameters after /?).

Thanks for your help

Comment: ok i mix a bit some basic rules ..i found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488401/query-string-breaking-page which help a bit ..in fact, no matter with the nature of the link (internal or external) , it's rather a matter with rewriting some urls parameters in htaccess..

Comment: hi again, any more comments on that ?  Some similar experience for instance would help (rewriting engine breaking urls destination) .. ..Tks

Comment: I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407606/htaccess-rewriterule-check-for-referrer-if-wrong-referrer-send-to-a-specific , it's nearly the reverse i 'd like to apply. Check for referrer, if it's the right one (ex: specific-domain.dom), don't apply any rewriting rules to the URI (thus avoiding a blank page for the visitor..)